# Next "n" Days Sales for every product

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(dd)
dt_op      quantity   product_code
20/01/18      1            613
21/01/18      8            611
21/01/18      1            613 
...
```

I am trying to get the sales in the dataframe of the **next "n" days**, but the following code does not compute them by `product_code` as well:

```
dd["Final_Quantity"] = [dd.loc[dd['dt_op'].between(d, d + pd.Timedelta(days = 7)), 'quantity'].sum() \
                        for d in dd['dt_op']]
```

I would like to define `dd["Final_Quantity"]` as sum of `df["quantity"]` sold in the **next "n" days**, for **every** **different** **product** in stock;

Ultimately, for i in `dt_op` and `product_code`.

```
print(final_dd)
n = 7

dt_op      quantity   product_code     Final_Quantity
20/01/18      1            613               2
21/01/18      8            611               8
25/01/18      1            613               1
...
```

Comment: Why in the desired output, there is third row with `product_code` = 613 and `dt_op` = 25/01/18?

Comment: Because it is another transaction

Answer (score 0):

Regardless how you wanted to present the output, you can try the following codes to get total of sales for every product for every `n` days. Let say for every 7 days:

```
dd.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='dt_op', freq='7D'), 'product_code']).sum()['quantity']
```